# Subroutine name beginning with underscore in Perl

Tags: perl

Here's an example from the Markdown source:

```
sub _StripLinkDefinitions{ somecode }
```

What does it mean? Is it just a convention or a part of the language?

Comment: Leading underscores often mean "private" or "do not use please" in more polite terms.

Comment: It's just a convention.

Comment: This is mentioned in [`perldoc perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html): "You can use a leading underscore to indicate that a variable or function should not be used outside the package that defined it."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an convention, documented in the [perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html):

> You **can** use a leading underscore to indicate that a variable or
>   function should not be used outside the package that defined it.

Also, in the [Perl best practices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do) page 49, says:

> **Prefix “for internal use only” subroutines with an underscore.**

with the explanation:

> A utility subroutine exists only to simplify the implementation of a
>   module or class. It is never supposed to be exported from its module,
>   nor ever to be used in client code.
>
> Always use an underscore as the
>   first “letter” of any utility subroutine’s name. A leading underscore
>   is ugly and unusual and reserved (by ancient C/Unix convention) for
>   non-public components of a system. The presence of a leading
>   underscore in a subroutine call makes it immediately obvious when part
>   of the implementation has been mistaken for part of the interface.

**Related**: The underscore has an special meaning too, as a part of a language - e.g.:

- the variable what's name is only the underscore, (check [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)) - e.g:

  - `$_` - The default input and pattern-searching space.
  - `@_` - list of all subroutine arguments
  - `_` - The special file handle what caches the information from the last `stat`or file test operator (such `-f`)
- language constructions what starts and ends with a double underscore, such: `__DATA__`, `__END__`, `__FILE__`, `__PACKAGE__`, `__LINE__`

Comment: also by convention (beyond just Perl), a sub named `_` is often used for i18n